# How to get related to ID objects from database

Tags: python, html, django, django-queryset

I am creating a website where i am using django database.The database will have one def called categories and one called gifi.So a gif will belong to a category and when one category will be clicked it will send the user to a page where all gifs that belong to that category will show up.I know that i should do something like requesting ID but i dont know the code

This is the models:

```
from django.db import models

class categorite(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Gifi(models.Model):
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='website/static/')
    emri = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Kodet = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    categoryId = models.ForeignKey(categorite, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

This is views:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import  Gifi,categorite
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'website/home.html')

def categories(request):
    content = {
        'view': categorite.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'website/categories.html',content)

def PostaCode(request):
    return render(request, 'website/PostaCode.html')

def Contact(request):
    return render(request, 'website/Contact.html')
def category(request,id):
    content = {
        'view':  categorite.objects.get(id=id)
    }
    return render(request, 'website/category.html',content)
```

This is urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('Home/',views.home, name='home'),
    path('Categories/', views.categories, name='categories'),
    path('PostaCode/', views.PostaCode, name='PostaCode'),
    path('Contact/', views.Contact, name='Contact'),
    path('Category/<int:id>/', views.category, name='category'),

    ]
```

This is the code that i use to show categories on my categories.html:

```
<div class="row p">
    {%for categorite in view%}
    <a class="c" href="{% url 'category' categorite.id %}">{{categorite.name}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

This video gives a quick show, how website is working now:
https://vimeo.com/user122082575/review/451987151/da98e3f75c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your views when you are asking for `Gifi` you should use the `<int:id>` which you provided from the url. So it will be something like this in your views: `Gifi.objects.filter(categoryId_id=id)` then you can pass that in your context.

Remarks that you have to fix:

- `categorite` is lower case it should `Categorite` also name always in english.
- `Source, Kodet` should be lower case, following the python convention.
- `id` is obsolete since that you always have `pk` and django knows when to convert `id` to `pk` while filtering results.
- `categoryId` should be just `category`
- a view function should always be in snake case. Eg `PostaCode` -> `posta_code`
- Fix your spacing between functions, classes
- urls should be in lower case.

Being consistent with your code is mandatory always follow the conventions for each language. For python that would be [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) or [black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style.html) please make sure you know these two.

Comment: "categoryId should be category_id", that is not 100% correct. If you think from Django's perspective, it creates a field named `category_id` automatically, if you name the field `category`(you can query using that or verify it from database tables). So "categoryId should be category"

Comment: Yes that's totally correct I was just translating it to snake case without thinking of that!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data using [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter) like this:

```
# view
def category(request,id):
    content = {
        'view':  Gifi.objects.filter(categoryId_id=id)
    }
    return render(request, 'website/category.html',content)

# template
<div class="row p">
{% for gifi in view %}
   {{ gifi.emri }}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use related objects to get data(using [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/) between `Gifi` to `Category`):

```
# view
def category(request,id):
    content = {
        'view':  Category.objects.get(id=id)
    }
    return render(request, 'website/category.html',content)

# template
<div class="row p">
{{ view.name }}  // category name
{% for gifi in view.gifi_set.all %}
   {{ gifi.emri }} // gifi information
{% endfor %}
</div>
```